# Add pubnub to angular2 cli project

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, pubnub

I want to add PubNub to an angular2-cli project. The problem is with the linking; however, I followed the instructions of the pubnub-angular2 package on npmjs.com.

When I try to load it in the browser, the error message is this:

> EXCEPTION: PubNub is not in global scope. Ensure that pubnub.js v4
>   library is included before the angular adapter

In the **app.module.ts**, I have the following:

```js
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {PubNubAngular} from 'pubnub-angular2';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [PubNubAngular],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

In the app.component.ts, I have the following code:

```js
import {Component, Injectable, Class} from '@angular/core';
import {PubNubAngular} from "pubnub-angular2";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

    title = 'Pubnub Chat Service';
    private channel = 'chat-demo-app';

    constructor(private pubnubService: PubNubAngular) {
        pubnubService.init({
            publishKey: 'pub-c-***',
            subscribeKey: 'sub-c-***'
        });
    }

    sendMessage(message: string): void {
        this.pubnubService.publish({
            channel: this.channel,
            message: message
        });
    }

}
```

Note that if I remove the import in the AppComponent, the component does not see the PubNubAngular provider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never used this library but it seems the error is pretty straightforward, you didin't import the main library but just the angular adapter. You need to include the library in your vendor.ts like `import  "myLibrary"` or add it to your index.html. before importing `pubnub-angular2` in the component/service that uses it.

Comment: Yes, it really seams straightforward; however, the solution is not so trivial to me. The vendor.ts is a 3rd party library that I cannot alter, while the browser cannot find anything when I refer to node_modules directory from the index.html (the node modules are on the same level as src, and the index.html is in the src folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from your code the only thing you could possibly be missing is the script tag needed in your index.html, make sure you add this...

```
<script src="node_modules/pubnub/dist/web/pubnub-angular2.js"></script>
```

Here is a plunker of `pudnub` being properly implimented.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jz9z6wArruL04qa2IY6h?p=preview)

**EDIT**

all steps to ensure you didnt skip any...

1. NPM install npm install pubnub
2. npm install pubnub-angular2
3. Include script to index.html (see above script
4. import to app.module `import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';`
5. Add provider to app.module `providers: [ PubNubAngular ]`
6. Import to any component using pubnub service `import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';`

**Angular-cli EDIT**

Remove the `<script>` tag from your index.html and add it to your `angular-cli.json` file like this...

`"scripts": ["../node_modules/pubnub/dist/web/pubnub.js", "./node_modules/pubnub-angular2/dist/pubnub-angular2.js" ],`

Comment: Thanks. After installing pubnub-angular2, the path to it is another one that you cited: `<script src="node_modules/pubnub-angular2/dist/pubnub-angular2.js"></script>`. Since I have the node_modules with one level up, I also tried to begin it with "../". In both cases, a 404 error is thrown.

Comment: @HorvathAdam navigate into your `node_modules` folder, do you see `pubnub-angular2`?

Comment: @HorvathAdam Also, you may not actually need the `<script>` tag... I have removed it from my local build and my app is still running without it.

Comment: Yes, it is there (pubnub-angular2 and pubnub, too).

Comment: First, I also thought that I do not need the script tag in the index.html. However, I did everything from your list except that.

Comment: @HorvathAdam updated for angular-cli import of `pubnub.js`

Comment: Thanks, you are awsome! The angular-cli.json had to be edited, nice job!