# How to integrate PubNub in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, pubnub

I'm trying to import/integrating my angular2 MEAN web application with PubNub. I got an error like:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: PubNub is not in global
>   scope. Ensure that pubnub.js v4 library is included before the angular
>   adapter

and i refered these links https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

i'm included angular2 pubnub '.js' files in index.html file globally like:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
> 
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js"></script>
>     <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
> 
>     <script src="node_modules/pubnub/dist/web/pubnub.js"></script>
> 
>     <script src="node_modules/pubnub-angular2/dist/pubnub-angular2.js"></script>
```

In Module.ts code enter like:

Imported file is

```
import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';
providers: [PubNubAngular]
```

In my Component Pubnub Init function placed like this:

```
 pubnubService: PubNubAngular;
constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService,
 private http: Http,
 private _ApiMessageService: ApiMessageService,
 private _errorService: ErrorService,
 pubnubService: PubNubAngular) {
     this.pubnubService = pubnubService;
     this.pubnubService.init({
            publishKey: 'XXX',
      subscribeKey: 'XXX'
     });
     this.pubnubService.subscribe({
      channels: ['Order' + this.orderId],
      withPresence: true,
      triggerEvents: ['message', 'presence', 'status']
    });
}
```

Comment: You code would be helpful otherwise we'd be guessing.

Comment: Above question has been edited with the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I removed all the includes and added 'pubnub.js' and 'pubnub-angular2.js' scripts in angular-cli.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6mjj.png)
as mentioned in 
[Satckoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767132/add-pubnub-to-angular2-cli-project)